# Logical Statement Error: object 'Solar.R not found'

Tags: r

I just started to learn R through Google Data Analytics Course.

I'm trying to extract data with specific condition by utilizing logical statement from 'airquality' database which comes with R, but I'm stuck right now, I guess it's very simple mistake but could not figure out what to fix.

```
> Solar.R > 150 & Wind > 10
```

I just copied and pasted above code from my course, but mine is getting following error

```
Error: object 'Solar.R not found'
```

The airquality database is below:

```
> airquality
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5      NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You have to use $ like this `airquality$Solar.R`

Answer (score 1):

I'm also starting R through Google Data Analytics Course; and likewise, encountered that problem while reading the material and doing a practice hands-on. I did couple of trials and here's how I did it:

```
df <-(airquality)
head(df)

newdf <- df[df$Solar.R > 150 & df$Wind > 10,]
head(newdf)
```

Output:

```
     Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
4       18     313 11.5   62     5   4
NA      NA      NA   NA   NA    NA  NA
NA.1    NA      NA   NA   NA    NA  NA
14      14     274 10.9   68     5  14
16      14     334 11.5   64     5  16
17      34     307 12.0   66     5  17
```

apparently, it should be a square bracket instead of parentheses and the statement should have a comma before the closing bracket.

As to why there should be a comma, and $ sign, I'm not there yet. Also pardon the "NA" values as I am still exploring how to get rid of those :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to *"As to why there should be a comma, and $ sign, I'm not there yet."*

```
newdf <- df[df$Solar.R > 150 & df$Wind > 10,]
```

A couple of notes:

- df means data frame.
- head () returns the values of the firsts rows
- $ is a common operator that gives access to the variables in this case, the columns Solar.R and Wind. In this activity we didn't have access to Solar.R.
- The trailing comma is use to extract rows and columns. Everything before the comma extracts rows, and after the comma columns ----> so with comma at the end, you are asking R to return all the columns available WHICH rows meet the conditions you ask ...In this case *Solar.R > 150 & Wind > 10*

I found this https://dzone.com/articles/learn-r-how-extract-rows